# How to set different liftime for different session variable in php?

Tags: php, session-variables, session-cookies

I have two session variable I want to set different lifetime for these session variable in same page.

```
$_SESSION['name'] = "example_name"; // lifetime - 3 days
$_SESSION['id']   = "example_id";   // lifetime - 7 days
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably be better off [setting regular (non session) cookies](http://php.net/setcookie) with the expiration you need. Most session cookies aren't going to survive 7 days.

If you really want to do it in the session, record some extra session variables with the expiration timestamps for each value, and check them yourself.

Comment: sessions lifetimes are hard to predict, so Paul's suggestion is a very good one